# VB.Net ListViewItemComparer No SortOrder

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and based on the documentations, the class `ListViewItemComparer` must accept the column index and the sorting order as arguments when instantiating the `ListViewItemComparer` class. But when i try, it has only 2 possible ways in instantiating this class. First one is by no-arg constructor, and 2nd is using column index.

[image]

Comment: All I can find is a custom definition for the class, it doesn't seem to be implemented in the Framework. Can you please link to the documentation article that you read?

Comment: The `ListViewItemSorter` property is type `IComparer`. That's an interface, not a class. It's up to you to create your own class that implements that interface and provides whatever functionality you need to sort as you want.  The documentation for the property includes a code example that will compare based on column so if that's what you want then simply copy that example.

Comment: Can you sort your data first? Say, with an Order By clause in your Select or if your data is in a List(Of T) sort by a particular property of T. After an initial sort use the built in Groups for other columns.

Comment: thanks @VisualVincent  , I just forgot that I created this as a custom class that implements the IComparer Interface, This is an old code that's why I thought `ListViewItemComparer` is not a custom one. Thanks. 

Thanks @jmcilhinney

Comment: @Mary I don't want to resubmit the query just because of some sorting functionality. Thanks for the idea by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] 
I updated the overriden compare function from the implemented `IComparer` interface. And created another constructor method that accepts sorting order.

```
Public Sub New(column As Integer, order As Integer)
        col = column
        ord = order
    End Sub

Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer _
                            Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare
        Dim returnVal As Integer = -1
        If (ord = 1) Then
            returnVal = [String].Compare(CType(x,
                        ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text,
                        CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)
        Else
            returnVal = [String].Compare(CType(y,
                        ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text,
                        CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)
        End If

        Return returnVal
    End Function
```