# BC30057 Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()... I don't get why this happens

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listview

I get this error on VB.net "BC30057 Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()'." as I am trying to do a sorting function on my listview. Here is the code with error:

```
 Public Class ListViewItemComparer
    Implements IComparer
    Private col As String
    Private order As SortOrder
    Public Sub New()
        col = 0
        Me.order = order
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub ListView2_ColumnClick(sender As Object, e As ColumnClickEventArgs) Handles ListView2.ColumnClick

    If e.Column <> sortColumn Then
        sortColumn = e.Column
        ListView2.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
    Else
        If ListView2.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending Then
            ListView2.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
        Else
            ListView2.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
        End If
    End If

    Me.ListView2.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer(e.Column, ListView2.Sorting)

    ListView2.Sort()

End Sub
```

the other code is in the comments

Comment: Implements IComparer

    Private col As String
    Private order As SortOrder

    Public Sub New()

        col = 0
        Me.order = order

    End Sub

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905866/vb-net-listviewitemcomparer-no-sortorder

Comment: Sorry to sound a little blunt but it seems quite clear.  Your constructor method takes no parameters, yet when you call it you’re passing two parameters into the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. As mentioned in the comments, you cannot create a new object passing in values to the constructor when you have no `Public Sub New` which is defined that takes those values. See below I have defined the constructor as `Public Sub New(column As Integer, order As Integer)`. Please note that you could create several different overloaded constructors if you wanted to, allowing the object to be initiated in different ways.

```
Public Class ListViewItemComparer
    Implements IComparer

    Private col As Integer
    Private ord As SortOrder

    Public Sub New(column As Integer, order As Integer)
        col = column
        ord = order
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare
        Dim returnVal As Integer
        If (ord = SortOrder.Ascending) Then
            returnVal = [String].Compare(CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text, CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)
        ElseIf ord = SortOrder.Descending Then
            returnVal = [String].Compare(CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text, CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)
        Else
            returnVal = 0
        End If
        Return returnVal
    End Function
End Class

Private sortColumn As Integer

Private Sub ListView2_ColumnClick(sender As Object, e As ColumnClickEventArgs) Handles ListView2.ColumnClick
    If e.Column <> sortColumn Then
        sortColumn = e.Column
        ListView2.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
    Else
        If ListView2.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending Then
            ListView2.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
        Else
            ListView2.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
        End If
    End If
    Me.ListView2.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer(e.Column, ListView2.Sorting)
    ListView2.Sort()
End Sub
```